# Avrogen strips out logicalType properties when generating C# classes

Tags: c#, avro, avro-tools

I'm using apache.avro.tools version 1.11.0 to generate C# types from my avro schema.

Here is a portion of the schema:

```json
"fields": [
  {
    "name": "ShipDate",
    "type": {
      "type": "int",
      "logicalType:": "date"
    }
  }
]
```

In the C# class the schema property contains `""fields"":[{""name"":""ShipDate"",""type"":""int""}`. As you can see the `logicalType` is missing.

If I compare it to:

```json
{
  "name": "BaseCost",
  "type": {
    "type": "bytes",
    "logicalType": "decimal",
    "precision": 7,
    "scale": 2,
  }
}
```

The C# class's schema property contains `{\"name\":\"BaseCost\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"bytes\",\"logicalType\":\"decimal\",\"precision\":7,\"scale\":2}}`.

Why has it swallowed some of the properties?

Comment: Voted to close as typo.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This was user error I'm afraid. The `"logicalType:"` field name has a semi-colon in it.

I'll give someone bonus points if they can tell me how to prevent errors like this in the future, with an avro-linter or something.